# why this file error class.phpmailer.php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

### message error

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_OLD_FUNCTION' or `T_FUNCTION' or `T_VAR' or `'}'' in D:\vhosts\vista.com.my\httpdocs\class.phpmailer.php on line 53
```

---

### class.phpmailer.php

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '<') ) exit("Sorry, this version of PHPMailer will only run on PHP version 5 or greater!\n");

class PHPMailer {

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // PROPERTIES, PUBLIC
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /**
   * Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low).
   * @var int
   */
  public $Priority          = 3;                    <!--line 53 is here-->

  /**
   * Sets the CharSet of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $CharSet           = 'iso-8859-1';

  /**
   * Sets the Content-type of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $ContentType       = 'text/plain';

  /**
   * Sets the Encoding of the message. Options for this are
   *  "8bit", "7bit", "binary", "base64", and "quoted-printable".
   * @var string
   */
  public $Encoding          = '8bit';
```

---

Answer (score 2):

If that is the proper line number of the error, then you are running PHP 4.

It doesn't have the `public` keyword, and thus you'll get a parse error before the runtime check can even do anything.

Comment: Wouldn't the first line comparing the current php version take care of that?

Comment: @Mike B, no. PHP has to parse the file first. If he is using PHP 4, the `public` keyword would trigger a parse error prior to the script even running.

Answer (score 0):

You never close the parenthesis `class PHPMailer {`.

Add a `}` to the end.